# Cuando entro a una web con usuario y contraseña para hacer scraping, me da la información como si no estuviese logueado

Tags: beautifulsoup

Quiero consultar unos datos que aparecen diferentes si estás logueado o no. En mi caso cuando me logueo en la web con usuario y contraseña accedo sin ningún problema, a continuación extraigo todas las url's para hacer scraping y cuando quiero obtener los datos que necesito me da la información como si no estuviese logueado. Utilizo las bibliotecas Request, BeautifulSoup y Selenium.

Una vez logueado copio en current_Url la url a la que quiero acceder, y cuando trato de ver la información con BeautifulSoup obtengo la información como si no estuviese logueado.

¿Por qué?

```
page = requests.get(driver.current_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cuando te logueas, guarda tu informacion de logueo en algun lado (usualmente una cookie).. si haces el pedido por otro lado, no tiene la cookie y no va a hacer lo mismo... pasaria igual si entraras desde otro navegador....